# ext4 on mdadm reverting data

Tags: ext4, mdadm

I have a problem with my home server setup. The problem is that sometimes, but really rarely, it reverts (for a lack of a better term) all my data back to an earlier state (somewhere between months and weeks earlier).

The setup is a 4TB ext4 on a Software RAID 5 with 3 disks running on an Ubuntu 12.04 (linux 3.2). Samba serves files of that partition.

`/proc/mdstat` tells me that the array is healthy `smartclt -H /dev/sdX` says PASSED for all devices. I tried to find something in the logs but I couldn't find anything suspicious.

Last time the error occurred I rebooted the server whilst using files on the shear however `fsck` didn't find any errors.

The nature of the error baffles me. Since ext is not a copy on write file system, I would have assumed something like this is impossible. If you can think of any diagnostics I can run, please don't hesitate.

I guess the question is what happened to my data and how can I stop it from happening again?

-- edit --

OK I found the error: 
The problem had nothing to do with ext4. The problem was the way I mounted the device.

I have the raid 5 for my data and a raid 0 with an backup. But the way I mounted this at startup was not 100% stable; sometimes the backup was mounted as the main.

From `/etc/fstab`:

```
# main RAID array
/dev/md126p1 /media/Main        ext4    defaults        0       0
```

From `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`:

```
# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/Main metadata=1.2 UUID=c2ccbd00:ce414404:0ee05911:eebe2832
ARRAY /dev/md/Backup metadata=1.2 UUID=b4973c41:e735e1c0:29e8be4b:4fe7c007 name=:Backup
```

Whoever can answer me this small question gets the bounty: What is the best way to mount the backup and the main in a guaranteed stable way.

--edit--

/dev/md/Backup:

```
    Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Sun Jun 19 15:45:35 2011
 Raid Level : raid0
 Array Size : 3907021824 (3726.03 GiB 4000.79 GB)
Raid Devices : 2
Total Devices : 2
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Sun Jun 19 15:45:35 2011
      State : clean
Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

 Chunk Size : 512K

       Name : :Backup
       UUID : b4973c41:e735e1c0:29e8be4b:4fe7c007
     Events : 0

 Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   1       8       81        1      active sync   /dev/sdf1
```

/dev/md/Main:

```
    Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Sun Jun 12 02:13:25 2011
 Raid Level : raid5
 Array Size : 3907021568 (3726.03 GiB 4000.79 GB)
Used Dev Size : 1953510784 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
Raid Devices : 3
Total Devices : 3
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Intent Bitmap : Internal

Update Time : Mon Jan 28 19:00:45 2013
      State : active
Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

     Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 128K

       Name : :Neue RAID-Anordnung
       UUID : c2ccbd00:ce414404:0ee05911:eebe2832
     Events : 17846

 Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8       49        0      active sync   /dev/sdd1
   1       8        1        1      active sync   /dev/sda1
   3       8       65        2      active sync   /dev/sde1
```

Comment: Do you maybe use snapshots or have a backup utility that restores data?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Thanks for your replay. There is no backup utility running (I do the backups by hand at the moment). AFAIK ext4 doesn't support snapshots (I don't use lvm).

Comment: Can you please provide your mdadm --detail for the above RAIDs? Why aren't you just mounting in /etc/fstab /dev/md/Main & /dev/md/Backup?

Comment: not using `/dev/md/*` was exactly the error. I believe that the `/dev/md*` labels are given to whatever superblock is detected first. So you agree that using `/dev/md/*` labels works as expected?

Comment: I've always used the /dev/md* labels when mounting RAIDs. The only other difference I can see is that I make use of LVMs on top of my /dev/md*. But that isn't mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to mount using UUIDs, in your `fstab`:

```
UUID=c2ccbd00:ce414404:0ee05911:eebe2832 /media/Main ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=b4973c41:e735e1c0:29e8be4b:4fe7c007 /media/Backup ext4 defaults 0 0
```

As pointed out by @Floyd, using labels is also nice, since you could create a new device with the same data and the same label if you need to change things. So you can do

```
tune2fs -L RAIDMain /dev/disk/by-uuid/c2ccbd00:ce414404:0ee05911:eebe2832
tune2fs -L RAIDBackup /dev/disk/by-uuid/b4973c41:e735e1c0:29e8be4b:4fe7c007
```

and then in your `fstab`:

```
LABEL=RAIDMain /media/Main ext4 defaults 0 0
LABEL=RAIDBackup /media/Backup ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Comment: UUID is definitely the way to go, unless you want to give your partitions names.

Comment: I had to use the UUID of the file system and not of the array. But other then that its dead on. I used `sudo blkid` to find out the UUID of the partitions.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment to the OP, all you need to do is just use the paths that were declared in the `/etc/mdadm.conf` file. You can use the **UUID** or **LABEL**, as [@Stefan Seidel](https://superuser.com/a/544374/20568) mentioned, but they're not really necessary.

#### Sample /etc/mdadm.conf

```
ARRAY   /dev/md0  level=raid1  num-devices=2  UUID=37d3cabc:42393031:23c133e6:3b879f08
ARRAY   /dev/md1  level=raid5  num-devices=3  UUID=47d4cabd:42393031:23c133e6:3b879f99
MAILADDR root@krycek,root@byers,root@frohike
```

#### Sample /etc/fstab

```
/dev/md0      /export/raid1           ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/md1      /export/raid2           ext4    defaults        1 2
```